# Auto brackets after print, input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Does VS Code have a function for writing brackets after printing automatically (Python)?

Where I can enable it?

Comment: Imagine you have a variable or function `print_data`. Then opening parentheses after you typed just `print` wouldn't be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **File > Preferences > Settings** to open the settings JSON file, you find "editor" or "autoClosing". It is enabled by default, but in your case, it seems not. What you have to do is just change user settings and enable it.